# sum items stor in array

Tags: arrays, sum

I have this code:

```
$str='ياسمين';

$a=utf8Split(trim($str));
for($i=0;$i<=strlen($a);$i++)
{

$sql_char=("SELECT num FROM alphabet where letters = '$a[$i]'");
$result = mysql_query ($sql_char,$dbConn);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
echo  $row['num'].'<br>';

}
```

Comment: it's hard to writ code here,, the output for code is :
10
1
60
40
10
50

I want to print sum items = 171
how I ca do it

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to add your `$row['num']` to a new `variable`

```
$sum=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo  $row['num'].'<br>';
$sum=$sum+$row['num'];
}
echo $sum; //171
```

**EDIT**

```
function mb_str_split( $string ) {
    # Split at all position not after the start: ^
    # and not before the end: $
    return preg_split('/(?<!^)(?!$)/u', $string );
}

$str   = 'ياسمين';
$charlist = mb_str_split( $str );

print_r( $charlist );
```

Comment: thanks a lot that's help me I want to know If I have  (360 - 9) = 351, I want to become 360 equal one of the following numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).